AnimAll animations not exporting
I have made several objects in my scene animate using AnimAll, and a few objects animate using standard object movement using keyframes. These play back just fine in my scene, but when I export as .FBX for use on Sketchfab, only the objects animated not using AnimAll are working.
Is there something wrong with my export settings?

Most likely the Blender fbx exporter only supports exporting native animatable properties, and isn't prepared to export arbitrary non vanilla addon data

I think so, too. The problem is not everything that works in Blender can be transferred via export in other file formats - I guess there are even some parts in Blender which can normally be animated without using AnimAll that FBX does not support, using the addon which allows to animate even more properties might result in just more FBX incompatible animations.

Thanks, do you think Baking Animations down would work around this and help this export?

What is it that you animated outside the standard? Can't it be done otherwise?

I animated some rope-like objects that were using a couple of modifiers like Solidify. I see now the error and that these should have been animated otherwise. What would be the best method for that?

It really depends what you animated and how. Could you [edit] your question and share your file with us so that we can check ourselves what's going on and give an adequate answer?

The short answer is, the only animation data you can consider to be able to reliably export through formats like FBX and also import on a target software are:

Object-level or bone-level transform keyframes (Location, Rotation, Scale)
Shape keys / Morph targets

If you exported to other 3DCC softwares (Maya, Houdini, some game engine, ...), you sometimes have the possibility to use the Alembic or USD formats, which allows caching pretty much any mesh deformation and even generation (including I.E. physic simulations, modifiers effects, ...). But I doubt a web model viewer will support that any time soon, that's usually reserved for resource intensive usages. Sketchfab in particular supports importing USD files but with strict limitations:

The USD (Universal Scene Description) format, which was developed by Pixar Animation for 3D movie pipelines, is intended for the transfer of rich 3D models and scenes. Given the richness of the file type, Sketchfab currently supports only a subset of its features.

File types: USD, USDA, USDC, USDZ
Model types: Static (i.e., not animated), Polygonal (e.g., not point clouds or NURBS)
Shaders: UsdPreviewSurface only

Source:
Sketchfab Introduces USD Upload Support - Sketchfab Community Blog


Thanks so much, this is very helpful in understanding my issue.
